# Was Haman rewarded for supporting Torah learners and building the Beis HaMikdash?

Tags: megillat-esther, tzedakah-charity, maseches-gitin, haman

The [Midrash Shochar Tov (22:25)](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.22.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> לשלשה חלקים נחלק ממונו של המן. שליש למרדכי ואסתר. ושליש לעמלי תורה.
> ושליש לבנין בית  המקדש - Haman's money was divided into thirds: 1/3 was given to Mordechai and Esther, 1/3 was given to those learning Torah, and 1/3 was given to build the Beis HaMikdash.

Was Haman rewarded for supporting Torah and the Beis HaMikdash? (The Gemara [Gittin (57b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.57b.7?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) says Haman's grandchildren reportedly learned in Bnei Brak - Shmaya V'Avtalyon who taught all of Klal Yisroel - but the Gemara doesn't say that was his reward per se)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we find anywhere that he was rewarded. (As always, it is hard to bring sources for a negative) When the money was used for these purposes, Haman was already dead. It was really Mordechai who inherited Haman who used the money for positive purposes.

Comment: Interesting - I was under the impression that when a deceased's money is given for Torah and the like (even if he didn't order that) then it is a zechus for him worth rewarding.

Comment: That is if the money was given by his inheritors as a merit for him, not when they are doing it against his wishes.

Comment: Definitely makes sense - have you seen anywhere make such a chiluk?

Comment: the question is...haman stole that money from the jews in jerusalem (terumas bais hamikdash).      so does he deserve to get any rewards???

Comment: also this premise says.     that paroh should be rewarded ,because his money supported the jews in the midbar, built a mishkan,etc

Answer (score 1):

Why should he be rewarded when he stole the money in the first place. The Pirkei D’Reb Eliezer 50 says אומר פנחס רבי
שני עשי רים היו לפנים בעולם ,קרח בישראל והמן בשושן . .שלקח כל אוצרות מלכי יהודה ואת כל
הקדשים קדשי אוצרות ,that Haman got his wealth from looting the treasury of the Kings
of Judah, and from all the treasuries of the Kodesh Hakedoshim.

On a side note, the Pirkei D Reb Eliezer writes that Haman was actually promoted to such a high position based on his stolen wealth .

Answer (score 1):

According to the Malbim, Haman's wealth went directly to Esther.
לכן נתן בית המן לאסתר, כי אחר שנהרג בשבילה נכסיו מגיעים אל המלכה, since Haman was killed on behalf of Esther his wealth was her right to receive.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Alan and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This source appears to argue on the Midrash in the question, which is intersting, but i'm not sure it qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemaara in Sanhedrin 96b says מבני בניו של המן למדו תורה בבני ברק https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=96b&format=text

Comment: sorry didn't notice that you already wrote that in the question

Comment: This would definitely be a great answer if you have a source which notes this was Haman's reward.

Answer (score 0):

The yaaros dvash 2/.  drush 15

says that most of hamans children and his wife were not killed and he had some kollel grandkids
was not just a story
It was a reward for giving the 10000 silver pcs to tzedaka for poor jews as per kings advice

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my question was based on a false assumption that Haman's money went directly to Mordechai and Esther. However, [some](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2833307/jewish/Chapter-Eight.htm) Meforshim explain that Haman's money first was taken by the royal treasury since that is the law for those killed by the king. Consequently, it was Achashveirosh who gave his own (Haman's confiscated) money to Mordechai and Esther...

Which makes me wonder: was Achashveirosh rewarded for that massive donation?